# Der Unterschied zwischen »verfaulen« und »verwesen«

Tags: difference, synonym

Laut dem *Duden* bedeuten die folgenden Verben:

> **[verwesen](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/verwesen):** sich (an der Luft) zersetzen; durch Fäulnis vergehen
>
> **[verfaulen](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/verfaulen)**: durch Fäulnis ganz verderben

Gibt es denn einen Unterschied dazwischen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Verwesung und Fäulnis sind zwei unterschiedliche Vorgänge.

**Verwesung** ist der durch Bakterien und Pilze bewirkte Abbau (menschlicher, tierischer oder pflanzlicher) organischer Substanzen **in Anwesenheit von Sauerstoff.** Verwesung findet also gewöhnlich nur bei Luftzufuhr statt.

**Fäulnis** ist die Zersetzung von (menschlichen, tierischen oder pflanzlichen) organischen Substanzen durch Mikroorganismen (hauptsächlich Bakterien) **bei Sauerstoffmangel.**

Ein größerer Körper wird deshalb an der Luft äußerlich überwiegend durch Verwesung und im Inneren überwiegend durch Fäulnis zersetzt. Mit fortschreitender Zersetzung kann daher durch die entsprechend verbesserte Sauerstoffzufuhr die Verwesung zunehmen. Dagegen kann bei unzureichender Sauerstoffzufuhr eine anfängliche Verwesung in Fäulnis übergehen, sobald der Sauerstoff verbraucht ist.

Comment: Also im biologischen Sinne sind es zwei unterschiedliche Vorgänge und im allgemeinen Sinne (siehe die zwei Antworten oben) ist Verwesen das Verfaulen der Wesen. Habe ich es recht verstanden?

Comment: @marmistrz Ja. Begriffe, die fachsprachlich genau definiert sind, werden umgangssprachlich nicht unbedingt genauso präzise unterschieden (z. B. „Zahl“, „Ziffer“ und „Nummer“). Die Wahl der Begriffe erfolgt stattdessen vielleicht einfach aus Gewohnheit, als Nachahmung von anderen Vorbildern, als Analogieschluss, nach selbstverfassten Regeln, intuitiv oder völlig willkürlich. Die Erklärungen in den anderen Antworten sind plausibel und in Bezug auf die Umgangssprache bestimmt nicht falsch. Womöglich gibt es sogar noch weitere plausible Erklärungsansätze.

Comment: Das ist zwar eine schöne Erklärung des Fachbegriffs, in der tagtäglichen Anwendung der Sprache "verwesen" allerdings nur Tiere und Menschen (Siehe Antwort von EM1 unten), während alles andere "verfault"

Answer (score 13):

Dinge können *verwesen*, wenn sie mal ein Wesen gewesen sind. Sie hören damit auf, ein *Wesen* zu sein. *Verwesen* ist dann das spezifische Verb fürs *Verfaulen* von Wesen.

Comment: Mich wurmt es, dass mir entgangen ist, dass im Wort "verwesen" "Wesen" steht. +1 für das gute Auge.

Comment: "Wesen" und "verwesen" haben zwar verschiedene Ursprünge, aber das ist eine gute Faustregel für das aktuelle Gebrauchsmuster der beiden Verben. Vielleicht beruht es ja auf diesem Gleichklang, weil die unterschiedliche etymologische Herleitung der beiden Wörter niemandem mehr bewusst ist.

Answer (score 10):

Tiere und Menschen verwesen; alles andere verfault.

So richtig gibt es keinen Unterschied. Im Kontext von Toten und Leichen hört man *verwesen*. Spricht man von Obst und Früchten, so ist das Wort der Wahl *verfaulen*.

Answer (score -3):

Mir scheint, Verwesung ist ein Oberbegriff von Fäulnis.

Comment: Wenn Verwesung der Oberbegriff ist, müsste dann nicht jede Fäulnis eine Verwesung sein? Analog zu: jedes Auto ist ein Fahrzeug (Oberbegriff). Ein fauler Apfel ist aber keine Verwesung.

Comment: Alles was verfault verwest. Das Faulen des Apfels ist ein Schritt im Verwesungsprozess.

Comment: Hm, ok, vielleicht im biologischen Sinne, aber nicht im sprachlichen Sinne. Und darum geht es hier.